# Javascript function throwing typeerror

Tags: javascript

I have declared a function below:

```
 var myFun = function(func){
        func();
    }
```

If I call the function like below:

```
myFun(function(x,y){console.log(x+y)}(3,4))
```

I am seeing the result but also getting a TypeError stating func is not a function. Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var myFun = function(func) {
   // you need to curry a function that can be called with your arguments
   return function(x, y) {
     // then pass the arguments to the callback
     func(x, y)
   }
 }
 
 // now to call myFun you would use
 // myFun(func)(x, y)

 myFun(function(x, y) {
   console.log(x + y)
 })(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the result of the function to your function and not a function. Try:

`myFun(function() { return (function(x,y){console.log(x+y)}(3,4)); })`

Comment: Why I am penalized with negative rating. I am a newbie to javascript.

Comment: I noticed that myself --- I'm not sure why. It seemed like a legitimate question myself.

Comment: I am also not sure whom to report to.

Comment: Me either... I think this is a problem they're aware of... though I can't recall that they've come up with a solution to it yet. It was addressed on one of their recent podcasts I believe.